# Is there a fixed term for an educational drop In AE?

Tags: word-request

I need to know what Americans call an 'educational lag' (when a student due to some problems faces a drop in their study processes);
For instance:

> - His studies have dropped substantially.

So what he has faced?

> - An education lag
> - An educational drop

Or what?

Comment: There is no fixed term for this. But an informal way of saying this is "He has been falling off lately" or "His grades have been suffering".

Comment: Thank you very much @TRomano ; just could you please tell me if my own sentence is used in everyday American English or it sounds too formal to you as a native speaker?

Comment: The adjective "educational" strikes my ear as a little off, though it would be understood.  A prepositional phrase would sound less like jargon.  "He has fallen behind *in his studies*".

Comment: So your recommendation is using "He has fallen behind / off in his studies lately"; thank you again @TRomano :)

Comment: "fallen behind in his studies" would work in formal, semi-formal, and casual contexts.  "fallen off" is at the casual end of the spectrum.

Comment: I guessed saying "his studies has dropped / declined substantially is too formal and not usable in everyday conversations. Thanks again.

Comment: If you wanted to make "studies" and not "he" the subject of the sentence: "His studies have suffered because of X problem".  That is neither too formal nor too casual.